# timed vc connection discord bot

Tags: python, timer, discord.py, bots

i made a vc music bot and i want it to start playing at certain set times. i did this but it is not working ( i am a beginner in python sorry if its a obvious mistake)

```
def checkTime():
    threading.Timer(1, checkTime).start()

    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
     
    if(current_time == '04:13:40'):
     play(ctx, 'https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
```

i tried to set times for the bot to play the audio in VC. didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is either with your play command or ctx which is not correctly set up. Without play command hard to tell the exact issue.

But you can do something like this:

```
def checkTime():
    threading.Timer(1, checkTime).start()

    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
     
    if(current_time == '04:13:40'):
        play()
```

Now all depends on your play command basically, you can use youtube_dl for this or just discord.py default thing:

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def play(url: str): #Pass your url, in this you can use url: https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
   voice_channel = ctx.author.voice_channel
   vc = await voice_channel.connect()
   vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url))
   vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(vc.source)
   vc.source.volume = 0.07
await vc.disconnect()

checkTime()
```

But I would suggest you to use schedule library instead threading in terms of simplicity and efficint.

In that you could do in one line only just after play command:

```
schedule.every().day.at("04:13:40").do(play)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Just make sure your play command is correct to run music at certain times